# Graphic Card Installation Failure (NV 9600M GT)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I wanted to switch from 7 to Ubuntu.

Now, the first thing that holds me back is the installation of the driver for my Nvidia 9600M GT.

Ubuntu recommends me 4 drivers from the "Additional Driver" Section.
Now, whatever driver I install, there are four things happening RANDOMLY after rebooting:

1. The pc freezes before seeing bootup splash
2. The pc freezes while seeing bootup splash image (ubuntu logo with the 5 dots)
3. The pc gets into login screen and freezes instantly (Thought the unity-bar is transparent now)
4. The pc freezes right after beeing able to login. (While this is happening the unity-bar changes from transparent to ugly-flat-style)

I also tried to install the official Nvidia .run file but after exiting the X-Server, it says the driver is not compatible with the kernel and exits installation.

Can somebody help me? I really wanna get rid of Windows :( But Ubuntu drives me perfectly insane.

Please answer as noobish as possible. I'm an expert Windows user, but Linux is absolutely new to me.

My Specs:
Ubuntu 11.10 installed from USB Stick (like 100 times now :/ because I dont know how to remove the driver in recovery mode)
9600M GT
4GB Ram
Intel Centrino 2 Dual Core 2.26GHz

Win 7 and Ubuntu running along side.

Thank you in advance, regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reach a console with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> after booting use `jockey-text`.

Use `jockey-text --help` for syntax.

Comment: Ok, so how does this help me?
I was able to install the driver again via console, but this freezed the computer again. 
Everytime, I have to reinstall Ubuntu, because I'm not able to disable the driver with "jockey-text --disable:nvidia_173" in recovery mode. Seemingly not all processes needed for that are started in recovery mode.
I cant reach the full console after booting, because the PC usually doesnt get into log in screen.

All 4 drivers, Ubuntu recommends fail, the original NVIDIA driver (I was able to install now), fails as well.

The graphic cards is working flawlessly in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same video card as yours. In Ubuntu 11.10 I installed the post-release Nvidia proprietary driver and it works. Some problems with shutdown, restart and logout, but Unity and login work without problems.
In Ubuntu 12.04, there is only an Nvidia driver suggested by Ubuntu and it works a little better than in Ubuntu 11.10.